Basic design for local folder indexing using any database
I'd like to ask about a design for using database as folder indexing on my local pc.
I'm using it for myself only thus there would be no user nor server concerns.
I've already written an user interface using pyside6 and I'm trying sqlite3 for the database.
This application works like ls in linux or file explorer in windows. It simply lists folder and files.
Creating folder indexes in the application is easy as I can just use insert into.
Same for deletion in the application, it's just delete it from database.
However if I delete them outside this application, the database would not know at all.
To solve this problem, at each start of this application/database, I need to scan all folders and check if they exist.
I think that there must be a better way to handle this.
I have a folder/file structure like this:
folderlevel1
folderlevel2
file1, file2, file3

There will never be a folderlevel3 or any new folders at any levels.
In the database, I would do:
key1 = folderlevel1_path
key2 = folderlevel2_path
values = file1_path, file2_path etc.

In my application, I would display a table with key1 and key2
so that when I double click on key2, it opens the key2 folder.
I don't need to open the files from the table.
What I'm thinking is updating the database each time I start this application.
folder: folderlevel1 folder names
database_folders = get all folderlevel1 names from database
for folder in database_folders:
if os.exist(folder): pass
else: delete folder from database

all_folders = get all folderlevel1 names from root folder, like a ls in linux
for folder in all_folders: 
if folder not in database_folders: insert folder into database
else: pass

since it's a local application, I won't have like 100 folders to check. However this just looks not clever nor elegant. I guess there must be a better way.

If you really needs this, then "there will never be a folderlevel3 or any new folders at any levels" is a red flag: design your system to deal with that anyway, because at some point you're going to change your mind, and the worst thing you can do right now is to not account for that.

Why in the world do you need to do this? The OS manages files and folders all by itself. What is the use case for trying to duplicate it in a database and adding all the maintenance overhead of keeping that database in synch with the file system?

@KenWhite I was asking myself the same question. Suppose that I have "bad" folder names like 1,2,3,4. I save their names like that in the database because otherwise they might contain special characters that are not allowed as folder names. I know that I should name them better but let's just say that I don't want to. In the database I'd like to have 'illegalfoldername?      ' mapped to folder 1. After some time I won't remember that folder 1 was supposed to have that illegal name thus I'll want to check the database.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks but I'm very sure there would never be a folderlevel3. I simplified the real question into this one. You can read my other comment. It's like I'd really want to keep the illegal folder names.

You don't allow bad folder names, and let the OS handle things. You're going to go bald trying to keep the file system in synch with your database. Just let the OS enforce validity of file names, and expect your users (and you yourself) to abide by the OS restrictions.
